# Calculate derivative with limit definition

Tags: calculus, limits

$f(x) = \frac{4x + 1 }{x -2}$ at x = 5.

We have only learned how to solve using First Principles, and I tried solving it like that but got a convoluted fraction. Then I tried keeping the $f(x+h)$ part the same but plugging $x=5$ everywhere for the $-f(x)$ part and ended up getting $-7$. But I couldn't get rid of $h$ in the denominator when I tried doing so. I was wondering what am I doing wrong? And what would be the best way to solve it if only using 1st Principles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compute
\begin{align}
f'(5)
 &= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(5+h) - f(5)}{h} \\
 &= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(5+h) - 7}{h} \\
 &= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\frac{4(5+h) + 1}{5+h-2} - 7}{h} \\
 &= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\frac{21 +4h}{3+h} - 7}{h} \\
 &= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\frac{21 +4h}{3+h} - 7\frac{3+h}{3+h}}{h} \\
 &= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\frac{21 +4h}{3+h} - \frac{21+7h}{3+h}}{h} \\
 &= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\frac{21 +4h - (21+7h)}{3+h}}{h} \\
 &= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\frac{-3h}{3+h}}{h} \\
 &= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{-3}{3+h} \\
 &= \frac{\lim_{h \to 0} (-3)}{\lim_{h\to 0}3+h} \\
 &= \frac{-3}{3} \\
 &= -1.\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

We want the derivative at $5$. So we want $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac {f(5+h)-f(5)}{h}$. Note that $f(5)=7$, so in this case we want 
$$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\frac{4(5+h)+1}{5+h-2}-7}{h}.\tag{1}$$

The numerator in (1) simplifies to $\frac{21+4h}{3+h}-7$. Bring this to a common denominator $3+h$, and nice things will happen.

Answer (score 0):

To compute the derivative at $x=5$ you need to compute $\frac {f(5+h)-f(5)}h$ and take the limit.

You should find that this is $$\frac 1h \cdot\left(\frac {4\cdot(5+h)+1}{(5+h)-2}-\frac {4\times 5+1}{5-2}\right)$$ and with some care, that should come out OK. You need to substitute $x=5$ in both parts.

Answer (score 0):

$$
f'(5)=lim_{h \to 0 }\frac{f(5+h)-f(5)}{h} = lim_{h \to 0 }\frac{\frac{4(5+h)+1}{3+h}-\frac{21}{3}}{h} = lim_{h \to 0 }\frac{-9h}{3h(3+h)} = lim_{h \to 0 }\frac{-3}{3+h}
$$
Then, $f'(5) = -1$.